# mysql-connector showing different behavior on Linux vs. windows machine

Tags: python, mysql, linux, windows, mysql-connector

I am developing a script on windows which at one point uses the mysql-connector library to download a snapshot of a table in MySQL into a csv file.

On windows, the script works properly every time, across various approaches.

The basic version of the script is:

```
importy mysql.connector

def get_snapshot():
    db_obj = mysql.connector.connect(blah blah)
    
    mycursor = db_obj.cursor()
    
    command = f'SELECT * FROM table_name'
    
    mycursor.execute(command)
    
    results = mycursor.fetchall()
    
    for row in results:
        #data handling and writing to csv
```

This worked perfectly on windows, but when tested on Linux, it only found the first 50 records of the table.

The linux host is remote and managed by my employer and the windows machine is my local development environment.

I tried doing this with a raw cursor and with a raw + buffered cursor. I also tried a paginated approach that only grabs 50 records at a time, worked perfectly on windows but again only got the first 50 records when ran on linux.

Eventually I tried to run some test commands on linux to see if it could even see beyond the first 50 records.

When running the query "SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 50,50", linux version reports 0 records found, while windows has no issue. I then try the same query, but with "LIMIT 100,50" at which point linux reports 36 records found (this is where I gave up lol).

So somehow linux sees the first 50 records, but not records 50-100 and then only sees 36 records in the 100-150 range. The table has 30,000 records total.

Comment: Do Windows and Linux connect to the same database server?

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby Yes, they are connecting to the same database server.